# Why is the function to update my progress slider called 3 times using addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uislider

Hello I've been trying to figure out this issue and don't know where to look. I'm using `AVPlayer` to play videos, and I have a `UISlider` whose value updates every second based on the progresss of the video using `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval`.

When I press pause, the `UISlider` thumb stops immediately as expected. However, immediately after I press play to resume the video, the thumb moves slightly before it continues progressing as normal every second.

I can't figure out why it's doing this. I'd like to have the `UISlider` thumb progress fluently, i.e. if I paused the video at 1.5 seconds in, and I play the video again, it SHOULD wait 0.5 seconds before the thumb moves again.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()

{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ....        

    isPlaybackSliderTouched = false

    isPauseButtonTouched = false

    setUpPlayerControls()

    ....
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let timeIntervalOne: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 10)

    playbackSliderTimer = avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(timeIntervalOne,
        queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { (elapsedTime: CMTime) -> Void in

        self.observeTime(elapsedTime)
    }

    ....

    playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: "onClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func observeTime(elapsedTime: CMTime)
{
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avPlayer.currentItem!.duration)

    if isfinite(duration) && avPlayer.rate == 1
    {
        print("ENNNTNTTERRR")

        let elapsedTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(elapsedTime)

        updatePlaybackSlider(elapsedTime: elapsedTime, duration: duration)
    }
}

func updatePlaybackSlider(elapsedTime: Float64, duration: Float64)
{
    if isPlaybackSliderTouched == false
    {
        let sliderValue: Float = Float(elapsedTime / duration)

        print("sliderValue = \(sliderValue)")

        self.playbackSlider.setValue(sliderValue, animated: true)

        self.currentTimeLabel.text = self.convertSecondsToHHMMSS(elapsedTime)
        self.endTimeLabel.text = self.convertSecondsToHHMMSS(duration - elapsedTime)

        print("currentTimeLabel.text = \(currentTimeLabel.text)")
        print("endTimeLabel.text = \(endTimeLabel.text)")
    }
}

func convertSecondsToHHMMSS(seconds: Float64) -> String
{
    let time: Int = Int( floor(seconds) )

    print("time = \(time)")

    let hh: Int = time / 3600

    let mm: Int = (time / 60) % 60

    let ss: Int = time % 60

    print("seconds = \(ss)")

    if hh > 0
    {
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hh, mm, ss)
    }
    else
    {
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", mm, ss )
    }
}

deinit
{
    avPlayer.removeTimeObserver(playbackSliderTimer)
}

func onClick(sender: UIButton)
{
    print("onClick")
    if sender == playPauseButton
    {
        print("playPauseButton touched")

        let playerIsPlaying:Bool = avPlayer.rate > 0 

        if (playerIsPlaying)
        {
            isPauseButtonTouched = true
            avPlayer.pause()
            sender.selected = true
        }
        else
        {
            isPauseButtonTouched = false
            avPlayer.play()
            sender.selected = false
        }
     }
}
```

Here's a sample output immediately after I press pause from play state:

```
setUpPlayerControls
viewDidAppear
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.0
time = 0
seconds = 0
time = 39
seconds = 39
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:00")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:39")
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 4.76564e-05
time = 0
seconds = 0
time = 39
seconds = 39
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:00")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:39")
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.0252767
time = 1
seconds = 1
time = 38
seconds = 38
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:01")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:38")
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.0505207
time = 2
seconds = 2
time = 37
seconds = 37
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:02")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:37")
handleSingleTap
onClick
playPauseButton touched
pause touched
```

Here's the continuing output when I tap the play from pause state:

```
onClick
playPauseButton touched
play touched
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.0718539
time = 2
seconds = 2
time = 36
seconds = 36
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:02")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:36")
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.0722224
time = 2
seconds = 2
time = 36
seconds = 36
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:02")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:36")
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.0757659
time = 3
seconds = 3
time = 36
seconds = 36
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:03")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:36")
ENNNTNTTERRR
sliderValue = 0.101012
time = 4
seconds = 4
time = 35
seconds = 35
currentTimeLabel.text = Optional("00:04")
endTimeLabel.text = Optional("-00:35")
```

As you can see the end of the first output when I press pause to the beginning of the second output when I press play, there is 2 unnecessary calls for time `00:02` to `observeTime(elapsedTime)`, which in turns call my `updatePlaybackSlider`, which in turn slightly shifts the slider value to the right a bit before it goes back to calling `observeTime(elapsedTime)` like normal, i.e. every 1 second.

What are some suggestions for me to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you are adding multiple time observers without realising? Set a breakpoint or NSLog at the point where you add the observer in viewDidAppear to see if you're adding too many.

Comment: viewDidAppear is called any time your view appears so it's obviously happening more than once. You need to add a viewWillDisappear method and remove your observer in that. Otherwise setup your observer in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: @amergin: I'm in the same view when this issue occurs, `viewDidAppear` is only called once and appears just once. I never switch back from a different view to this view. I'm just "pausing" and "playing" an Avplayer state in the same view. Therefore, relocating this to `viewDidLoad` or adding it to `viewDidDisappear` does nothing.

Comment: Try changing CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 10) to CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 10000). The second value is the precision of your CMTime.